# numpy install error

Tags: python3, numpy

## Background

[Instructions indicate installing numpy](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/06/getting-started-with-the-nvidia-jetson-nano/) in a python virtual environment (log below).  The log indicates warning and errors: although the install process indicates 'Success', the warnings / errors indicate uncertainty.  That being said:

## Questions

1. What are the problems associated with said errors & warnings?
2. Is there a test that can confirm there will be no problems?
3. How can the install command be improved so as to avoid the same errors / warnings?

## LOG

```
(deep_learning) user@nanite:~$ pip install numpy
WARNING: The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/4b/f9f4b96c0b1ba43d28a5bdc4b64f0b9d3fbcf31313a51bc766942866a7c7/numpy-1.16.4.zip (5.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.1MB 942kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  WARNING: Building wheel for numpy failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/6b'
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... done
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.4
```

## UPDATE

Permissions:

```
(deep_learning) user@nanite:~$ ls -l /home/user/.cache/pip
total 12
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Jun 28 22:31 http
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Jun 28 22:19 selfcheck.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 28 22:08 wheels

(deep_learning) user@nanite:~$ ls -l /home/user/.cache/
total 84
drwx------ 3 user user  4096 Apr 21 07:38 chromium
drwx------ 2 user user  4096 Jun 28 18:02 compizconfig-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 20480 Jun 28 22:16 event-sound-cache.tdb.ebe5a0d15af94384af2e1f235d4e00f0.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
drwx------ 8 user user  4096 Apr 21 07:32 evolution
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Apr 21 19:24 fontconfig
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user  4096 Apr 22 07:33 gnome-software
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Jun 28 19:51 gstreamer-1.0
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user  4096 Apr 21 07:32 ibus
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Apr 21 07:32 ibus-table
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     0 Apr 21 21:47 motd.legal-displayed
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jun 28 22:19 pip
drwx------ 5 user user  4096 Apr 21 19:16 thumbnails
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user  4096 Apr 21 08:30 totem
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Apr 22 07:57 unity-lens-photos
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Apr 22 07:58 unity-lens-video
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user  4096 Apr 21 07:33 update-manager-core
drwx------ 2 user user  4096 Jun 28 18:03 wallpaper
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    11 Jun 28 10:40 zeitgeist-vacuum.stamp
(deep_learning) user@nanite:~$
```

Comment: Your update shows that it's owned by root. Change ownership back to user.

Comment: @vidarlo  I agree with your solution in the sense that this will resolve the permissions problem.  Hopefully chown will not introduce new problems

Comment: I can't think of any sane reason why a file or directory in `/home/user/cache` should be owned by root. There's no reason for that. It is extremely unlikely to introduce problems to change ownership. Not changing ownership *will* lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: The directory `'/home/user/.cache/pip/http'` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> WARNING: The directory `'/home/user/.cache/pip'` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The error message is rather straight forward: It says `/home/user/.cache/pip` is not owned by current user. It tells you to check permissions and owner of that directory.

This you can do with `ls -l /home/user/.cache/pip`.

It should, as (almost?) all files in the home directory, be owned by the user. If it is not owned by user, change ownership with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/user/.cache/pip
```

Here we have to use `sudo`, as users cannot normally change ownership of files.

Comment: Update the OP to reflect permissions of said directories: both are owned by root and lack the 'w' permission to write.

Comment: Owner has write permission, which is what is needed. It should be owned by user, not by root. Thus, change ownership, and you'll be OK.

Comment: It would future-proof your answer if you at least suggested that pip3 could be used instead of pip for installing numpy, and this would also require creating a Python 3 virtual environment if a virtual environment was also required.

Answer (score -1):

The permission denied error means that you have to use **`sudo`** before the install statement.

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

That should do it.

Comment: Per the link, my understanding is that sudo is not necessary in a virtual environment.  When I saw the permission error, I can see why the recommendation is to use sudo.  What am I 'missing'?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028735/4953146

Comment: @gatorback You are entirely correct. There's no reason to use sudo. This answer advocates brute force sudo-use, which is likely to introduce new problems down the road.

Comment: I am trying to understand if there is a problem and how to diagnose any problem.  Also would be good to understand how to avoid future error warning / errors

Comment: @gatorback see my answer. It's basically the wrong owner of a directory.

Comment: Agreed, no reason to use sudo, it would have just prevented the permission denied writing to that cache folder.  numpy should be installed ok for you.  The next step is to test it, create a program and do a `import numpy as np` if it gives no error then everything is ok.

Comment: And further down the road, you have an virtual environment not owned by the user using it, leading to new problems. It's not a nice solution.

Comment: @vidario  Please clarify the virtual environment ownership issue in your answer and any suggested remedy / best practice to avoid this problem?